# Cannot use 'email' field instead of 'username' in OAuth2 Plugin for CakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp, authentication, oauth-2.0, cakephp-2.3

**Explanation:**

Attempting to use this OAuth2 Plugin for CakePHP:

https://github.com/thomseddon/cakephp-oauth-server

Have followed the instructions, and am now going to this URL:

```
http://mysite/oauth/login?response_type=code&client_id=NGYcZDRjODcxYzFkY2Rk&
    redirect_url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.return_url.com
```

(We had made a client in the database with the same info he used in the example)

It brings up a log-in box for Email and Password, but fails authentication every time.  I believe it's failing because by the time it gets to [Cake's `FormAuthenticate->authenticate()` method](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/master/lib/Cake/Controller/Component/Auth/FormAuthenticate.php), the settings have reverted to `'username'=>'username'` and `'passwordHasher'=>'Simple'`.

If we add these lines to the [FormAuthenticate](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/master/lib/Cake/Controller/Component/Auth/FormAuthenticate.php) (above `$fields = ...`):

```
$this->settings['fields']['username'] = 'email';
$this->settings['passwordHasher'] = 'Blowfish';
```

Then the log-in works successfully.

**Things We've tried:**

Putting this in our AppController, the [OAuthAppController](https://github.com/thomseddon/cakephp-oauth-server/blob/master/Controller/OAuthAppController.php), the [OAuthController](https://github.com/thomseddon/cakephp-oauth-server/blob/master/Controller/OAuthController.php) (all in beforeFilter):

```
$this->OAuth->authenticate = array(
    'userModel' => 'Members',
    'fields' => array(
        'username' => 'email'
    )
);
```

We've tried changing it to the new format like 2.3 in all of those places, as well as in the initial $components array in my AppModel:

```
$this->OAuth->authenticate = array(
    'Form' => array(
        'passwordHasher' => 'Blowfish',
        'fields' => array('username'=>'email', 'password'=>'password'),
    )
);
```

**Closing:**

At this point, I'm looking for any way (other than modifying the actual CakePHP core) to get it to be able to log-in with `email` instead of `username` (and hopefully that will solve the same issue with having it revert from Blowfish to Simple as well.

We've already tried heavily modifying the OAuth Plugin (to no avail) and aren't opposed to trying that again, but we can't figure out what to change.

Comment: Have a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15090917/using-oauth-for-authentication-with-cakephp-2-3  User uses `$new_user['User']['username'] = $user['email'];` -- might give you some insight?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using this in the OAuthController:

```
$this->OAuth->authenticate = array(
    'Form' => array(
        'passwordHasher' => 'Blowfish',
        'fields' => array('username'=>'email', 'password'=>'password'),
    )
);
```

Change it to this (notice removal of the "O" so it calls the regular "Auth"):

```
$this->Auth->authenticate = array(
    'Form' => array(
        'passwordHasher' => 'Blowfish',
        'fields' => array('username'=>'email', 'password'=>'password'),
    )
);
```

Or, take it a step further, and set your `$this->OAuth->authenticate` array in your own AppController, then, in the OAuthController do this (instead of the above):

```
$this->Auth->authenticate = $this->OAuth->authenticate;
```

Comment: brigevans is GENIUS. You don't even know how long we spent trying to get this to work... THANK YOU.